# Select by all possible combinations from several lists of values for each field

Tags: sql, jpa

For example, I have an entity with fields `f1 f2 f3`. And I have 3 lists with values `(1 2) (3 4) (5 6)`.

Is it possible to do something like:

```
select e from entity where f1=? and f2=? and f3=?
```

but for each conbination of values from lists? So, I want to replace multiple selects with values:

```
1 3 5 
1 3 6 
1 4 5 
1 4 6 
2 3 5 
2 3 6
```

but in one query?

Comment: So you do not want all values, just one row, but with variable condition f1 f2 f3?

Answer (score 0):

Yes,

Here's a quick example :

```
SELECT e FROM entity WHERE f1 IN (?,?) and f2 IN (?,?) and f3 IN (?,?);
```

with arguments `1,2,3,4,5,6`

if you have undetermined number of arguments, you can generate an array of `?` tokens with the right amount of arguments for each field then throw them in the right order for binding.